# How can I set Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 as my system path and still run Code block GNU GCC compiler?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, gcc, simulink

I am writing my C/C++ codes used codeblocks as my IDE. In addition, I need to run Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 to convert my matlab simulink to c/c++ code.

Please how can I have both my codeblocks and Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 working?

Comment: Maybe you can use #ifdef?

Comment: @eyalm, please can you explain your comment?

Comment: The C preprocessor allows you to compile diferent parts of the code depends on the compiler or environment. The idea is to use a flag (either built-in or a one you create) and decide which parts of the code should participate. I am not sure regarding your specific requirement but this is the generic way.